# Random Number Generator Inside a var element is giving the same output each time its called on

Tags: javascript, random

So I'm trying to make a JS project that involves RNG (random number generation).

I'm using a `var` object with the random number generator in it. Heres an example of what I'm talking about:

```
var RNG = Math.floor(Math.random() * (863 - 768 + 1)) + 768;
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = RNG +"&nbsp"+ RNG +"&nbsp"+ RNG;
```

I'm expecting this to give 3 different random numbers in the element with the ID "output". I instead get 3 of the same random number.
What can I do to get 3 different random numbers instead of 3 of the same random numbers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using a function instead of a variable. A variable's value gets computed only once (unless you re-assign it later on) and then **the result** is saved in it for future uses. So a function is more adequate to your problem.

Something like this:

```
function RNG() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (863 - 768 + 1)) + 768;
}

document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = RNG() +"&nbsp"+ RNG() +"&nbsp"+ RNG();
```